# cakephp 3 how to use plugins (Imagine)

Tags: php, cakephp-3.2

In my cake app a need [Imagine](https://imagine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/introduction.html) but how I can create instance of class Imagine in Controller.

Plugin was install by composer and all files are in vendor folder.

This:

```
 require 'vendor/autoload.php';
 $imagine = new Imagine\Gd\Imagine();
```

doesn't work.

I get:

> require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory [APP/Controller\ArticlesController.php, line 100] Fatal
>   error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required
>   'vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp_blog\src\Controller\ArticlesController.php on
>   line 100

Comment: Try with backslash `'vendor\autoload.php'` I think you are in windows and this path is for linux.

Comment: If things have been installed correctly, you don't need a "require" at all. The `autoload.php` should be included automatically by Cake, meaning you can go ahead and just create the object.

Comment: Ok it's work but only in model table file when I add behaviour but why? In controller app doesnt see imagine class I have a lot of problems with plugins.